# How to use INDEX MATCH in Google Sheets when the two values are formatted differently (text versus numbers)?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to match a string of numbers (like 370488004) using the typical INDEX MATCH formula. Unfortunately, in one range the numbers are formatted as plain text, and in the other range they are formatted differently. Usually 'Automatic' or 'Number'. I want to avoid having to update the formatting of both ranges whenever the values get updated (usually via a paste from an outside source). Especially since it's not always going to be me doing the updating.

Is there a way I can write my INDEX MATCH formula so that it ignores the formatting of the values it's attempting to match?

The value returned by the INDEX formula can be in any format. Plain text, number, doesn't matter. The problem is the two values I'm matching are in different formats. I need a formula that ignores that their formatting.

Here's an example sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cwO7HGtwR4mRnAqcjxqr1qbhGwJHLjBKkp7-iwzkOqY/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **VALUE** or **INT** to force it into a number value, or if you want to keep it text use **TEXT**. Example would be:

```
=INDEX(VALUE(D1:E4),MATCH(G1,E1:E4,FALSE),1)
```

The numbers in column D are in fact **text**, but utilizing **VALUE** first for the range puts them all in number format. It is finding the value associated with "Green" written in G1. Without seeing a working example sheet this is the best solution I can offer.

**UPDATE**:

You can use VLOOKUP array with a static range (otherwise error), or QUERY to have the range infinite.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(VALUE($G3:$G5),$B3:$C,2,FALSE))

=QUERY(FILTER($B3:$C,$B3:$B=VALUE($G3:$G)),"Select Col2")
```

[image: enter code here]

Comment: Here's an example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cwO7HGtwR4mRnAqcjxqr1qbhGwJHLjBKkp7-iwzkOqY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: `=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(VALUE($G3:$G5),$B3:$C,2,FALSE))` would work then. Be sure to set your range accurately.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like ARRAYFORMULA and VALUE did the trick. Your answer is using VLOOKUP, but I was able to switch that to INDEX(MATCH( and it worked just fine for me.

Comment: Yes you can use Index Match such as `=INDEX(B3:C5,MATCH(VALUE(G3),VALUE(B3:B5),FALSE),2)` be sure to set each both columns B and G to values to ensure there are no errors. The only downside is you cannot use index match as an array, hence the VLOOKUP/QUERY method. So you would have to drag the formula down to all the participating rows.

Comment: That's fine. I'm using this in a filterable/sortable table. And if memory serves, formulas like FLATTEN(), FILTER(), and ARRAYFORMULA() don't work with that. But since INDEX/MATCH inside of ARRAYFORMULA only returns one single result I'm fine doing that.